# Reducing the memory assigned to an array

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say I have an array of `char` containing a sentence, and I want to copy that sentence in a different array but filtering a certain character:

```
char a[] = "hello everybody";
char b[sizeof(a)];
char idontwantyou = 'e';
int it = 0;
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(a); ++i)
    if (a[i]!=idontwantyou)
        b[it++] = a[i];
```

I had to allocate the same amount of memory for `b` than the size of `a` because I don't know the size of the sentence without the undesired characters right?

Now, I have my `b` array with the sentence `hllo vrybody'@·`&¡` right? I mean, there is "trash" at the end of the array.

Is there any way I could "cut" the trash in the tail so the size of `b` is the same value than `it`?

I just copied `b` in a new array I defined as `char c[sizeof(b)]` but this doesn't seem like a good practise.

Maybe `realloc` in `b` would do what I want?

Comment: At first glance I don't see any problems with your code. `b` will be null terminated.

Comment: I assume that your question is actually C related. Please remove the C++ tag, because this code is not (reasonable) C++. If you want C++ advice, remove the C tag and start looking into [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).

Comment: @self. yes, it will be nullterminated in the `sizeof(a)` position, including that "trash"

Comment: @dabadaba No, the null terminator is immediately after `y`. OP is just printing incorrectly.

Comment: @self. I am OP and I am telling you that `sizeof(a)==sizeof(b)`

Comment: How are you printing b??

Comment: but ``sizeof(b)!=strlen(b)``

Comment: @dabadaba, would it be acceptable to remove the unwanted characters from the string pointed to by 'a'?  (In my view, that would greatly reduce the amount of memory required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(b)` would be equal to `sizeof(a)`, because that is the actual size of `b`. To use [`realloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc), you have to allocate `b` using [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) in the first place.

That would be done in a way similar to this:

```
char a[] = "hello everybody";
/* better use strlen here -- it will also work with char*, and not only with
   statically allocated arrays */
char *b = malloc(strlen(a)+1);

/* your code here */

char *tmp = realloc(b, it);
if (!tmp) {
    free(b);
    /* some error here! */
} else {
    b = tmp;
    /* continue working with b */
}
```

There are some important bits in here:

- You have to manually `free` `b` after you’re done, because it is allocated on the heap instead of the stack, and thus you have to release the memory on your own instead of it getting released automatically on the function exit.
- The return value of `realloc` may be NULL. In that case, the old memory is still allocated and you have to do some kind of error handling (as sketched with the if).
- If `realloc` succeeds, `tmp` points to the new memory area and `b` is invalid, which is why we override `b` with `tmp`.

Comment: what I was trying to do is precisely avoid the use of a third variable. can't you just reallocate b in itself?

Comment: @dabadaba No you can’t. This is in fact a mistake many programmers do, and which I did for myself until recently. realloc can fail, and if that happens, the original memory will be left unfreed. There is no other API function which automatically frees the memory, even on failure, but you can write it yourself in a few lines of C.

Answer (score 1):

In-place elimination of unwanted character, and allocated array size reduction:

```
char *a = strdup("hello everybody");
char idontwantyou = 'e';
char *b = a;
char *c = a;
```

Eliminate unwanted character:

```
while(*b)
   {
   if(*b != idontwantyou)
      {
      *c=*b;
      ++c;
      }   

   ++b;
   }

*c='\0';
```

Reduce the size of the allocated array:

```
b=realloc(a, strlen(a) + 1);
if(NULL == b)
   /*Handle error... */;
a=b;
```

Test results:

```
printf("array = \"%s\"\n", a);
```

Output should be:

```
array = "hllo vrybody"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to run two passes over the string, one to count and one to copy.

You should evaluate the problem in terms of how much this operation matters in the
overall cost and cpu+memory profile of the program.  Most likely, it hardly matters at all.
In which case, the simplest is probably the best.